# how to make image appear as background through css from a local image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an image appear as the background to a div tag with the id of "background". When I do it through html it works fine but I'm trying to do it through css and thats when it doesn't appear. Here is the code from the css file.

```
#background{ 

background: url('ipadLayout.png');

}
```

Html Code:

```
<div id="background"></div>
```

Folder Structure:
MainFolder
-main_style.css
-ipadLayout.png

Also tried this structure:

MainFolder
-assets
/ipadLayout.png (this file is in the assets folder)
-main_style.css

Comment: Where's the image located and where is the css located from page's root path?

Comment: the image is in a folder called "assets" but both of the css and the assets folder are under the "main" folder. I have tried moving the image to be directly in the same directory as the css file and it still not working.

Comment: Add some html code and folder structure and i can help

Comment: Try using `background-image` instead of `background`. I can't see that making a difference, but it's something to try.

Comment: if the css and the "assets" folder are under the "main" folder, then it should be `background:url('assets/ipadLayout.png');`, no?

Comment: I have tried both of the suggestions and still not working.

Comment: Have you given a minimum height and width to background div? Or else the div is considered empty and background image wont be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<div id="background"></div>

#background{
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: i have an image named bg in folder named images

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is that the `<div>` has a width and height of `0px`. Set this to your CSS with the `width` and `height` changed to your image's width and height.

```
#background {
    background-image: url('ipadLayout.png');
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#background{

  background: url(ipadLayout.png) no-repeat; 
  min-width:320px;
  min-height: 300px;
  display:block;

}

<div id="background"></div>
```